# AWS XRay regex servicename filter

Tags: aws-xray

I have services for different git branches. And would like to have Service Map drawn for each branch separately.
For this I need to create a Group for each branch (provide some filtering condition that will match only traces corresponding to the branch I want).
My services have branch specified in their names. E.g. UserService-BRANCH_NAME
Is there a way to filter out all services that have name that contains some text?
There is CONTAINS filter in Xray console documentation, but it is not applied for service names.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-filters.html

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do what you are saying but instead of doing it as part of service name I would do a separate annotation. Segments in your traces can have annotations which are essentially key value pairs containing extra information about your traces which you can layer filter on. You can create an annotation say branch_name in your traces and then create a group for each branch with filter `annotation.branch_name =...`. You can also do contains instead of = if you want.