# AWS XRay Filter Expression name CONTAINS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I'm looking at the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-filters.html#xray-console-filters-details) and there is a **string keyword** for **name** and a string operator **CONTAINS**. What I am trying to do is put these together, to match all services that contain a substring (to be able to see a specific workflow).

However, when I try `name CONTAINS "example-string"` or even `service() {name CONTAINS "example-string"}` I just receive "There was an error while creating the group. Try again later".

I'm aware I could reference each service manually, but I am looking for a way to make this a bit quicker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS XRay regex servicename filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934771/aws-xray-regex-servicename-filter)